# Undefined references to GLFW / Vulkan although libraries seem to be linked

Tags: c++, linker

I'm a C++ beginner with some experience in Java trying to set up a project using GLM, GLFW, and Vulkan on Windows. This is going to be my first time getting my hands dirty in a lower-level language like C++. I'm having a lot of trouble getting the compiler to link the Vulkan and GLFW libraries to my project. I'm following the tutorial [here at vulkan-tutorial.org](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_Setting_up_Visual_Studio) to get started. Here's the code in main.cpp:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan window", nullptr, nullptr);

    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

    std::cout << extensionCount << " extensions supported\n";

    glm::mat4 matrix;
    glm::vec4 vec;
    auto test = matrix * vec;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the commands being used to compile it:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -fexceptions -g -IC:/glfw-3.2.1/include -IC:/glm-0.9.9.1/glm -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.82.1/Include -IC:/glfw-3.2.1/include -c "src/main.cpp"
g++ -LC:/glfw-3.2.1/lib-mingw-w64 -LC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.82.1/Lib -o VulkanTest.exe main.o -lglfw3 -lvulkan-1
```

The first command compiles the .cpp into a .o successfully, but the second command gives me errors from the linker. Every single reference I made to a member from Vulkan or GLFW is undefined. (Path has been shortened for easier reading)

```
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties@12'
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `glfwDestroyWindow'
[omitted]/src/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
```

It seems like the linker can't find the library files I provided with -L and -l, but if I change -lglfw3 to -llibglfw3.a or -lglwf3.dll, I get this:

```
[omitted]/mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibglfw3.a
```

or

```
[omitted]/mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3.dll
```

Leading me to think that the linker DID find the libraries at first, since it didn't complain about being unable to find the library - but why can't it find sources for the references to GLFW / Vulkan functions? I have no idea what's happening. Is it finding the library files?

I'm using GLFW 3.2.1, Vulkan SDK 1.1.82.1, MingW GCC version 6.3.0, and I'm running on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: The linker is finding libraries that satisfy the options `-lglfw3 -lvulkan-1` but
the ones it finds do not provide definitions for the symbol references it
needs to resolve. They are not the right libraries for your compiler. We
cannot say why without knowing exactly what your compiler is (as per the
output of `g++ -v --version`), where you got the libraries and how you installed them.

Comment: I listed the versions of GLFW, Vulkan, and MingW above. I'm using [GLFW 3.2.1 64-bit windows pre-compiled binaries](https://www.glfw.org/download.html), the [LunarG Vulkan SDK 1.1.82.1](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#windows), and MingW GCC 6.3.0 (returned from output of "gcc --version")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out my problem was rooted in using an old version of MingW. Originally I downloaded MingW from [here](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/p15522), which was recommended by [the guide on MingW's wiki](http://mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started). I updated to 8.1.0 from [this site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) and the linker began throwing errors about undefined references to different functions, such as "__imp_CreateDCW" and "__imp_SwapBuffers".

I happened to recognize these as GDI functions from some other research I did. I added GDI32 to the libraries option in the linker and the build went through successfully.

Now my build commands are as follows:

```
g﻿++ -std=c++11 -fexceptions -g -IC:/glfw-3.2.1/include -IC:/glm-0.9.9.1/glm -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.82.1/Include -c "src/main.cpp"
g+﻿+ -LC:/glfw-3.2.1/lib-mingw-w64 -LC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.82.1/Lib -o VulkanTest.exe main.o -lglfw3 -lvulkan-1 -lgdi32
```

Comment: I didn't have the _exact_ same problem you had, but also I didn't know to include `-lgdi32` in the linker flags until I read your answer, so thank you!